# Pattern java : 2 caracters less than n times and their sum of appereance less n too

Tags: java, matcher

I want to find if a string started with one character (bewteen 1 and 9 occurrence) and a second character (bewteen 1 and 9 occurrence too), but their sum of appearance must be (exactly) 10, the total must be 10.
Number of first char + Number of second char = 10.

I want to know if it is possible to do it in one time, or if it's impossible : if I should do it in 2 times.

My first character is a space :  "\s" 
My second character is a number, but not 0 : [1-9][0-9]*

But you can explain with character a and b, I will adapt it after.

```
String w = "         1"          //ok
String x = " 123456789"          //ok
String z = "  123456789"         //must be not ok (11 char)
String y = "         123456789"  //must be not ok

Pattern my_pattern = patter.compile("^\\s+[1-9][0-9]*");
Pattern my_pattern2 = patter.compile("^\\s{1,9}[1-9][0-9]{1,9}");
```

The **my_pattern** is not good, he allowed too many pattern.

The **my_pattern2** made a restriction on the number of space and the number of digit but not on the sum, how could i do it ?

A solution is to write the 9 possibilities like that :

```
Pattern my_pattern3 = patter.compile("(a{1}b{9}|a{2}b{8}|a{3}b{7}|etc)");
```

but I would prefer a general solution if you have it.

Thanks you for your attention

Comment: The string _must start_ with the character? If so, it would be easier to understand to just code the constraints you mentioned. Also, it's unclear what you mean by "sum of appearance".

Comment: Sorry "sum of appearance" is the number total of the 2 characters a et b. The sum of number of a and the number of b must be 10.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Jules and welcome to stack overflow!

TLDR; The answer you've already given is the only way to do this with a regex

To answer your question we need to talk about Regular Expressions, which is what the java `Pattern` class is using to match text strings (wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)). Regular Expressions can only match a small class of patterns, called Regular Languages. They famously can't be used to check if brackets match:

```
(((())())())() <-- Like this
```

The problem that we run into here is that regular expressions can't check if there is the same number of something (i.e. opening and closing brackets). This is quite similar to your problem of checking that the two lengths add up to ten. However because in your case there is a finite number of possibilities (unlike matching brackets) it is possible to do this, but only by enumerating all the possible cases as you have already done. I'm afraid there isn't a better way to do this with just a regex.